# SignalR and Redis

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, servicestack.redis, signalr-backplane

I've got a project that uses SignalR and a RedisBackplane, we've moved from StackExchange.Redis to ServiceStack.Redis due to Redis Sentinel compatibility issues (Not movable)

However, it now looks like the support for SignalR Redis Backplane seems to be tied into StackExchange?

Have I completely missed something, or is there support for ServiceStack on a SignalR Redis Backplane?

Current code looks like:

```
 var redisConnection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(this.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Redis"));
            services.AddSignalR(o => { o.EnableDetailedErrors = true; })
                .AddStackExchangeRedis(options =>
                {
                    options.Configuration.ChannelPrefix = "Audit";
                    options.ConnectionFactory =
                        writer => Task.FromResult(redisConnection as IConnectionMultiplexer);
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe anyone has implemented a SignalR Redis backplane using [ServiceStack.Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis).

ServiceStack does have it's own [real-time events solution using SSE](https://docs.servicestack.net/server-events) which includes a [Redis Server Events](https://docs.servicestack.net/redis-server-events) implementation that uses ServiceStack.Redis (akin to SignalR Redis backplane).

Answer (score -2):

I prefer to use username/password in the configuration

```
//StackExchange.Redis for configuration options
 var redisConfiguration = new ConfigurationOptions
            {
                EndPoints = { "serverinfo:portinfo" },
                User = username,
                Password = password
                //,Ssl = true
            };

            signalRBuilder.AddStackExchangeRedis(options => { options.Configuration  = redisConfiguration; });
```

Comment: That's great, and thanks for that, but it wasn't really what was asked.

Comment: :) when I was trying to use username/password in SignalR Redis, I didn't find proper information to implement it. So just added my comment to those who're trying for it.

Comment: Thanks for that, but it's still not relevant *for this question*, I would suggest creation your own question, and then you can also answer it yourself with your own answer